# LibreOffice how to get filepicker multiple file selection data

Tags: vba, libreoffice, basic

In LibreOffice 4.2 I am trying to open the file picker and select multiple files (which I succeeded), and then to transfer the names (and path) of those files to a variable (or array, does not matter).

Although I can open the file picker and select multiple files, I can get the file name and path of only one file (the first one). And I couldn't find any way to get the others.

I am using the following code:

```
Sub TakeFile()
   Dim FileNames(0 to 100) as String
   FileNames() = fImportLocalFile()
   Msgbox FileNames
End Sub

Function fImportLocalFile() 'as String
' FJCC: Can't define the function as returning a String because now it returns an array
   'this function opens a system file open dialog box and allows the
   '   user to pick a file from thier computer to open into the
   '   document for processing

   'stores the filedialog object
   Dim oFileDialog as Object
   'stores the returned result of the activation of the dialog box
   Dim iAccept as Integer
   'stores the returned file name/path from the file dialog box
   Dim sPath as String
   'stores the set default path for the dialog box
   Dim InitPath as String

   'stores the types of files allowed in the filedialog
   Dim sFilterNames as String

   'setup the filters for the types of files to allow in the dialog
   sFilterNames = "*.csv; *.txt; *.odt; *.ods; *.xls; *.xlt; *.xlsx"

   'create the dialog box as a Windows File Dialog
   oFileDialog = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.ui.dialogs.FilePicker")

   'set the filters for the dialog
   oFileDialog.AppendFilter("Supported files", sFilterNames)

   'set the path as blank
   InitPath = ""

   'add the default path to the dialog
   oFileDialog.setDisplayDirectory(InitPath)

   'setup the dialog to allow multiple files to be selected
   oFileDialog.setMultiSelectionMode(True)

   'set iAccept as the execution of the dialog
   iAccept = oFileDialog.Execute()

   'execute and test if dialog works
   If iAccept = 1 Then
      'set sPath as the chosen file from the dialog
      'sPath = oFileDialog.Files(0)
      FileArray = oFileDialog.getFiles() 'added by FJCC
      'set the function as sPath for returning to the previous sub
      fImportLocalFile = FileArray  'modified by FJCC
   'end current if statement
   End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is you are assigning the array of selected files to the funtion name itself! Choose a different name.

This works with me on LO 5.0.0.5

```
SUB TakeFile()
'   Dim FileNames(0 to 100) as String
'   Dont limit yourself!

   FileNames = fImportLocalFile()

   path = FileNames(0)
    FOR i = 1 TO Ubound(FileNames)
       print path + FileNames(i)
    Next 

End Sub
```

and within the function:

```
path = FileArray(0)
FOR i = 1 TO Ubound(FileArray)
   print path + FileArray(i)
Next 

fImportLocalFile    = FileArray
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Interface `XFilePicker2` which "extends file picker interface to workaround some design problems." This Interface has a Method `getSelectedFiles`.

See https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/ui/dialogs/XFilePicker2.html.

Use this Method instead of `XFilePicker.getFiles`.

The following should work:

```
Sub TakeFile()

   Dim FileNames() as String
   FileNames = fImportLocalFile()

   Msgbox Join(FileNames, Chr(10))

End Sub

Function fImportLocalFile() as Variant

   Dim oFileDialog as Object
   Dim iAccept as Integer
   Dim sPath as String
   Dim InitPath as String

   Dim sFilterNames as String

   sFilterNames = "*.csv; *.txt; *.odt; *.ods; *.xls; *.xlt; *.xlsx"

   oFileDialog = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.ui.dialogs.FilePicker")

   oFileDialog.AppendFilter("Supported files", sFilterNames)

   InitPath = ""

   oFileDialog.setDisplayDirectory(InitPath)

   oFileDialog.setMultiSelectionMode(True)

   iAccept = oFileDialog.Execute()

   If iAccept = 1 Then
      fImportLocalFile = oFileDialog.getSelectedFiles() 
   Else
      fImportLocalFile = Array()
   End If

End Function
```